# Multiplying boolean and string pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

i'm looking to merge two series by "multiplying" them. One series is boolean and one String. Let's say this is df:

```
df=
        a     b
    0   1     abc
    1   1     cde
    2   1     NaN
    3   0     a123
    4   0     b123
    5   0     NaN
```

I want to get a Series c that looks like this:

```
      c
0    abc
1    cde
2    NaN
3    0
4    0
5    0
```

i've tried

```
df['c']=df['a'].multiply(df['b'])
```

and it did not work. i got:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try `mask`

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,0,0,0], 'b':['abc', 'cde', 'NaN', 'a123','b123','NaN']})
df['c'] = df['b'].mask(df['a']==0, 0)
df
```

The output:

```
    a    b     c
0   1   abc   abc
1   1   cde   cde
2   1   NaN   NaN
3   0   a123    0
4   0   b123    0
5   0   NaN     0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can using `where`

```
df.b.where(df.a.astype(bool),0)
0    abc
1    cde
2    NaN
3      0
4      0
5      0
Name: b, dtype: object
```